# What was the price of a Winchester-Drive for the HP-85 desktop computer back in 1980?

Tags: hardware, price

I wrote my first computer programs in HP-Basic on a HP-85 desktop computer. The year was 1980 and we stored our programs on special "high-speed" cassette tapes. I remember proposing to buy a "Winchester-Drive" for our lab, but our management refused to approve the purchase because of its ridiculously high price tag. Does anybody remember how much the price of a Hard-Drive was in those days? And what storage-capacity we were dealing with?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The July 1983 HP-85 price list](http://www.hpmuseum.net/document.php?catfile=410) includes the following stand-alone Winchester drives:

- 9134A (just under 5MB) for $3,500
- 9134B (9.6MB) for $4,360

These were also available as combination drives with 3.5” or 5.25” “flexible” drives.

As [Raffzahn](/users/6659/raffzahn) points out, for comparison, the price for the HP-85A *computer* is given as $2,750, and the B model was $2,995, so a single hard drive cost significantly more than the computer it would end up attached to (and there were cheaper Series 80 models). $3,500 in 1983 is equivalent to $9,600 today (see [this inflation calculator](https://www.usinflationcalculator.com/)).

(All prices are given in US dollars.)

See also [ST-506 price: wholesale or retail?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5196/79) and [How much did the first hard drives for PCs cost?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17163/79)

Comment: To add some reference, 3.5k (which was not overly expensive) is not only past 10k of today's money, but also more than the machine itself did cost (2..3k). I always get lost when trying to understand how far we have come. The price of several Gig of ultra fast solid state 'drives' is more driven by packaging and shipping cost than the device itself. There is not even a remote way to explain that in a relatable way to young folks. To me that's about the worst point when doing tours.

Comment: Indeed, and then you get to supercomputers...

Comment: Oh yes. But there at least the basic explanation about the value of being able to automate some operation at all, vs. not being able is something the students do understand. Most still remember the value of a simple calculator vs. having to do a triangle by hand :)) With super computers I do use a scale of tasks to show improvement between generations - which in addition nicely starts out in very relatable improvements (like the curvature of a wing) and slowly turning into less and less every day related needs. I wish the same could work for storage.

Comment: @Toby and in the case of the UK most US suppliers had had a habit of: 200$ = 200 UK pounds.  I checked out prices for a Epson MX 80: 500 $ at launch while in Sweden the price from one of the resellets was 5000 crowns (with the crown-$, that price was 25 % larger) and oh yes the price is excluding VAT !

Comment: So the drives must have been significantly more expensive in 1980, maybe about CHF 7500 or USD 4500 for a 5MB drive at that time.

Comment: @CEOtech4lifeapps the drives only show up in [HP’s catalogs](http://hparchive.com/hp_catalogs) in 1983. There might have been 85A-compatible drives available elsewhere in 1980, but I don’t know how much they would have cost — bear in mind that a ST-506 on its own cost $1,500 in late 1980.

Comment: @CEOtech4lifeapps These were the very first drives in reach for micros at all. Think how expensive the first reasonable sized SSDs were.